# How to manage releasing individual features with Git (bitbucket) + Jenkins?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am using Git (bitbucket) + Jenkins flow to manage releases for my client. We have only two envs `TEST` and `PROD`. I am following below simple flow. (I am not sure that it's useful or not but I am using `.war` artifact with `Java` project and `Maven` as build tool)

**NOTE :** `test` is branch and `TEST` is environment throughout this post

- Create local branch per feature from `master`
- Do changes on local and create PR with target = `master` per feature
- Merge PR with `master` if code changes looks fine
- Release `master` on `TEST` env
- If all looks good on `TEST`, I release `master` on `PROD` env

But there are problems (as mentioned below) with about flow like,

- If there are multiple features (let's say `Feature-1`, `Feature-2`, `Feature-3`) moved on TEST one by one with minimum gap, and I want to release only `Feature-2` on PROD, then above flow does not help me

To figure out above problem, I tried something like this,

- Created a branch called `test` from `master` on bitbucket
- Create local branch per feature from `master`
- Do changes on local and create PR with target = `test` per feature
- Merge PR with `test` if code changes looks fine
- Release `test` on `TEST` env
- If all looks good on `TEST` for particular feature, then I create second PR for same feature with target = `master` on `PROD` env
- Release `master` on `PROD`

But there are problems with this approach too, I am trying explain the problem with below scenario

- Let's say I have created PRs for Feature-1, Feature-2, Feature-3 (one by one sequentially with some gap) with target = `test` branch and merged all branches
- While doing above, I have to take pull from `test` for each PR otherwise I can't merge it with `test` branch
- Now, let's say I want to release only Feature-2 on `PROD` so when I create PR with target = `master` for Feature-2 branch, it also comes with Feature-1 changes (because I had to taken pull from `test` and Feature-1 was already there on `test`) which is not desired.

My basic goal is to be able to release any feature anytime on any env. I am sure git provides many facility to do this but I can't figure it out due to my knowledge limitation on `Git`. Is there anybody who can help me with above?

Thanks in advance for your time to read this post.

Answer (score 0):

did you consider to use a configuration table to activate/deactivate features in your PROD environment? Something like drool.

You protect all your features by a variable, and you activate this var it in test, for example. When your feature is sign-offed, you can go activate it in PROD.

If everything is protected, it doesn't matter which pull request you ship into PROD.

If you switch to this new process, you might want to add a 3rd phase PRE-PROD, where your settings are exactly the same as your PROD environment.

Comment: Nice suggestion, appreciate it but I would love to keep this stuff limited to git, if possible

Answer (score 0):

you need to ocrestrate with `master` branch only, so for your last scenario:
you have 3 PRs with target `test` and all 3 branches was created from `master`, what you will need to do is to merge `master` back to test and all other not yet merged fetaure branches after one branch is merged to `master` in that way you will be safe (ofc , from time to time you will have merge conflicts, but it is expected).

Comment: Hi @BigGinDaHouse : Thanks for your answer, but I am not able to understand your approach, can you please explain bit more that how can it solve the problem?

Comment: it is all the same as you do in your second approach , but instead of merging back to feature branches ```test``` branch merge ```master``` branch

Comment: But it can't resolve my problem. Right? I can't deploy Feature-2 separately on PROD

Comment: you can , for example, if Feature-1 do not pass your tests on TEST env , will mean that it will not be merged in master branch (which is your PROD). And the TEST will be always fresh with master + Feature-* branch, ofc you need to care about that

Comment: but in that case, I can deploy only the single feature on TEST at a time, that should not be limitation, right?

Comment: single env single branch, that was always a limitation and if you want to be not limited , condier using docker instances as TEST environemnts and deploy different branches to there